# php ftp_chmod not working on file, but ftp_site does, why?

Tags: php, ftp, chmod

I am trying to automate some steps for a website.   Using PHP FTP commands.

The problem I am running into is changing the permissions on a folder I just created.   I can create the folder using `ftp_mkdir`, no problem... but the permissions are not set correctly.  I can't, by default, upload to that folder.

I tried...

```
$dir="/test_folder/";
ftp_chmod($conn_id,0777,$dir);
```

This never changed the permission.   I tried a regular FTP program with the same credentials, that worked.

I read somewhere on the net to try...

```
$chmodCmd = "CHMOD 0777 ".$dir;
ftp_site($conn_id, $chmodCmd);
```

this works.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What command does the "regular FTP program" use to change the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are identical.

The only small difference is that your `ftp_chmod` code results in

```
SITE CHMOD 777 dir
```

while the `ftp_site` code results in

```
SITE CHMOD 0777 dir
```

Note the leading zero. But that should not make a difference. If it does, it's a problem of the server.

(tested with the latest PHP 5.6.9)